# Php, html, css, jquery etc can solve it

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = $db->query("YOUR QUERY HERE");
echo '<select name="DROP DOWN NAME">';

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    echo '<option value="'.$row['something'].'">'.$row['something'].'</option>‌​'; 

}

echo '</select>';
```

Question : How to to it by using foreach loop.

Comment: format that in code.

Comment: $query = $db->query("YOUR QUERY HERE"); 
echo '<select name="DROP DOWN NAME">'; 
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['something'].'">'.$row['something'].'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';

Comment: dude if you are going to keep using StackOverflow you are gonna have to learn how to format your code.

Comment: Does this work for you? If it does why change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$resultSet = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($resultSet as $intIndex => $arrAssoc) {
     print_r($arrAssoc);
     $column = $arrAssoc['someColumn'];
     // etc
}
```

Comment: It would be a help if you can explain the code as well. That helps in understanding the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating through every value you will need to fetch all data and store it in an array. Generally speaking, `while($row=$query->fetch())` is a better option

```
foreach ($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
{
echo ''.$row['something'].'';
}
```